# How does the Standard support this call of a pure virtual function in the base class S?

Tags: c++, c++11, lookup, language-lawyer

Consider this snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
struct S {
    virtual void pure1() = 0;
    virtual void pure2() = 0;
};

struct T : S {
    void pure1() { std::cout << "T::pure1" << '\n'; }
    void pure2() { std::cout << "T::pure2" << '\n'; }
};


void S::pure2() { std::cout << "S::pure2" << '\n';}

int main()
{
    T t;
    t.S::pure2();
}
```

It prints `S::pure2`.

Looking at the C++11 Standard, I don't know exactly how does that happen. I believe it has to do with §3.4.5/4:

> If the *id-expression* in a class member access is a *qualified-id* of
>   the form
>
> class-name-or-namespace-name::...
>
> the *class-name-or-namespace-name* following the . or -> operator is first looked up in the class of the object expression and the name, if
>   found, is used. Otherwise it is looked up in the context of the entire
>   *postfix-expression*.

But I don't understand how the pure virtual function `pure2()` is found in the base class `S` with the expression `t.S::pure2();` above.

Comment: Why shouldn't it be found? It's right there for anyone to see.

Comment: You are using the private inheritance, that is not an "is-an" polymorphism and has weird rules. Try changing the `struct T : S {...}` to `struct T : public S {...}` and see what happens.

Comment: @TalesM struct inheritance is public by default.

Answer (score 5):

It is OK for a pure virtual function to be implemented in the base class. The standard specifies that to be valid (emphasis mine):

> **10.4 Abstract classes**
>
> 2 An abstract class is a class that can be used only as a base class of some other class; no objects of an abstract class can be created except as subobjects of a class derived from it. A class is abstract if it has at least one pure virtual function. [ Note: Such a function might be inherited: see below. —end note ] A virtual function is specified pure by using a pure-specifier (9.2) in the function declaration in the class definition. **A pure virtual function need be defined only if called with, or as if with (12.4), the qualified-id syntax (5.1).**

If you didn't call

```
t.S::pure2();
```

then, it will be OK to omit implementation of `S::pure2()`. It will be a link time error if you didn't implement `S::pure2()` but still called

```
t.S::pure2();
```

Comment: Where is this `qualified-id syntax` in 5.1?

Comment: @ChairmanMao, the *qualified-id* syntax is under Section 5.1.1/8.

Comment: I think you've got the answer. But I still don't understand why the paragraph I quoted above does not apply to the lookup of the name `pure2` in struct S. Do you have anything to say about this?

Comment: @ChairmanMao The paragraph you're quoting lists the production as "*class-name-or-namespace-name* `::` ... " and then talks about how the *class-name-or-namespace-name* is looked up. That's the part **before** the `::`.

Answer (score 2):

The bit you're quoting covers the lookup of `S` in the expression `t.S::pure2()`. It doesn't apply to the name `pure2` at all.

The relevant ruling here is 10.3/15:

> Explicit qualification with the scope operator (5.1) suppresses the virtual call mechanism. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> class B { public: virtual void f(); };
> class D : public B { public: void f(); };
> void D::f() { /* ... */ B::f(); }
> ```
>
> Here, the function call in `D::f` really does call `B::f` and not `D::f`. *—end example* ]